# Creating child records with parent model and return nested in response

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopback

I am currently working on a project which is using the [loopback](https://loopback.io) framework.  It is extremely frustrating in I feel as if I am fighting with this framework to get something extremely simple done.  I simply need to create newly created associated instances when a request is received to create a parent instance with information for the children.  I have gotten it working to the point where it does in fact create the children but when I try to set the property so I can return both the parent and children in the response... it doesn't actually set the children property.  What is going on here??? (**edit** I assume the model instances implement setters/getters to prevent overriding some of the properties it sets)

I can't find anything in the documentation about doing something simple like this.  The most I can find is retrieval of nested models.  I can't seem to find anything on creating them without sending 20 requests when I have a parent with many children.

```js
module.exports = function(Parent) {
  Parent.on('dataSourceAttached', () => {
    const create = Parent.create.bind(Parent);
    Parent.create = async (data, opts) => {
      const { Child } = Parent.app.models;
      let instance;
      try {
        instance = await create(data);
        if (data && data.children && Array.isArray(data.children)) {
          const { id: parentId } = instance;
          const children = await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
            Child.create(
              data.children.map(m => Object.assign({}, m, { parentId })),
              opts,
              (err, res) => (err ? reject(err) : resolve(res))
            )
          );
          instance.children = children;
          console.log(instance.children === children); // false (wtf... #@#$#$%)
        }
        return instance;
      } catch (err) {
        // handle err
      }
    };
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain this in simple terms.

Suppose you parent model is `Library` and your child model is `Book`. So now Library hasMany Books and Book `belongsTo` Library right.

Now you can create `Library` and `Books` like the following

```
Library.create({
  name: "Library"
}, function(err, library) {
  // here library is created
  // Now if you have set relation, one can create books inside library like below
  library.books.create(book_array_data, function(err, books) {
    // here books are created
  })
})
```

Here I've mentioned `Library.books` where `books` is the relation name in `Library` model

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: My problem is neither the relationship nor the the creation of the actual child instances.  This I can perform just fine.

Parent:  `instance = await create(data);`
Children: `const children = await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>`


  What I would like to do is return both the parent with the created children nested in the response.  I actually solved this by not returning a model instance (using `.toJSON` on parent and children).  I am certain it isn't ideal and I would assume there should be some way to do this using loopback but this

Comment: yes, I think this is the only way. But if you are willing to make another call, maybe you get the desired result.

Comment: Yes, I can make another call with the query parameters loopback provides but the whole point was to not have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I currently solved this by calling `toJSON` on all model instances and then modifying them as desired before returning the shape I wanted.  I expect there must be some way to do this using loopback without this type of thing... but I still have yet to figure it out.  Any further answers are still very much welcome.

```js
module.exports = function(Parent) {
  Parent.on('dataSourceAttached', () => {
    const create = Parent.create.bind(Parent);
    Parent.create = async (data, opts) => {
      const { Child } = Parent.app.models;
      try {
        let children;
        const instance = await create(data);
        if (data && data.children && Array.isArray(data.children)) {
          const { id: parentId } = instance;
          children = await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
            Child.create(
              data.children.map(m => Object.assign({}, m, { parentId })),
              opts,
              (err, res) => (err ? reject(err) : resolve(res))
            )
          );
        }
        const resp = Object.assign(instance.toJSON(), {children: children.map(child => child.toJSON());
        return resp;
      } catch (err) {
        // handle err
      }
    };
  });
};
```